# C language - Can't check getchar() is alphabet or digit

Tags: c

Please tell me why my `else if` does not work?
I'm trying to check if the input value is correct or not.
If it is not `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` it will out put an error!
Everything works okay except the `else if`!
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name;
    int len = 0;

    printf("Enter the user name: ");
    name = getchar();

    while (name != '\n')
    {

        name = getchar();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= (sizeof(name)/2); i ++)
        {
            len++; 
        }
    }

    printf("len = %d\n", len);

    if((len < 5) || (len > 10 ))
    {
        printf("Output: input is invalid"); 
    }
    else if((isdigit(name)) || (isalpha(name))) //this one does not work
    {
        printf("invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Output: input is invalid");
        return 0;
    }   

    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: because according to your `while` statement your 'name' after finishing the loop is `\n` which is neither a digit nor a letter.  it is a 'space'.

Comment: so, should I change to do-while?

Comment: You need check in while-loop. Also digits is not alphabets. So I do not think it is necessary to check by isdigit.

Comment: @ManDang changing the loop type will not help you. you will need to change the algorithm in accordance to what you want to do.

Comment: ok, I'm changging  @Serge

Comment: If 'name' is declared as type char, then sizeof(name) is one. Your loop body will be executed once and only once, since sizeof(name)/2 is zero. Your loop then breaks down to the simple statement 'len++;'

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use the debugger (`gdb`) e.g. to run your program step by step to understand what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the intent of this program is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isdigit raises a debug assertion when entering £ and ¬](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077229/isdigit-raises-a-debug-assertion-when-entering-%c2%a3-and-%c2%ac)

Comment: Note that I voted as a duplicate to *guide you away from the erroneous belief that `getchar` should be stored into a `char`*... Tell me, which [`getchar` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getchar.html) are you reading which suggests that's a good idea? Or are you just guessing? Because you *can't* hope to learn to write portable C code by *just guessing*.

Comment: We've answered questions almost exactly like this too many times. Did you ever think to read the "help center" and/or do some searches for already existing [`isdigit`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+isdigit), [`islower`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+islower), etc so on and so forth questions? Because I bet if you did, you'd have found your answer quite quickly!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this program? Are you trying to store a string in `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the message printed before reading value in `name` is *Enter the username* and as usernames are usually strings, I suppose you are reading a string and not a single character.

If that's the case, change

```
char name;
```

to

```
char name[20]; //20 is just a number. Make it bigger if you need
```

because a string is just a sequence of characters which may be stored in a character array.

You could use `fgets()` to read into `name`.

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

fgets will stop reading when a `\n` is encountered but the `\n` will be stored in `name` as well.

So replace the `\n` with `\0` to mark the end of string.

```
name[strlen(name)-1]='\0';
```

For finding the length of the string with `strlen()` for storing into `len`.

```
else if((isdigit(name)) || (isalpha(name))) //this one does not work
{
    printf("invalid");
}
```

If you are checking the last character entered into `name` in the `else if`, it may be re-written as

```
else if(isalnum(name[len-1]))
{
    printf("invalid");
}
```

`isalnum()` will return non-zero if its argument is alphanumeric.

---

Now in case you really did mean `name` to be a single character and just need the last entered character for comparison in the `else if`.

If `name` is a `char`, `sizeof(char)` must be `1`. So

```
for (i = 0; i <= (sizeof(name)/2); i ++)
{
    len++; 
}
```

is equivalent to just

```
len++;
```

as `sizeof(name)/2` is `0`.

Note that `getchar()` returns an `int` and not a `char` and the value returned is `EOF` if some error occurred.

Try

```
while (name != '\n' && name != EOF)
```